# Read only mode for Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an interactive Ruby on Rails application which I would like to put into a "read only mode" during certain times.  This will allow users to read the data they need but block them from actions that write to the database.

One way to do this would be to have a true/false variable located in the database that was checked before any write was made.

My question.  Is there a more elegant solution for this problem out there?

Answer (score 15):

If you really want to prevent any database write, the easiest way I can imagine would be to override the `readonly?` method of a model to always return true, either in selected models or maybe even for all ActiveRecord models. If a model is set to readonly (normally done by calling `#readonly!` on it), any try to save the record will raise an `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` error.

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def readonly?
      true
    end
  end
end
```

(actually untested code, but you get the idea…)

Comment: This is potentially an interesting solution.  How would I toggle readonly mode on and off on the fly for a specific model?

Comment: By monkeypatching ActiveRecord::Base, it'll affect all models (I thought that's what you were looking for). You could write some fancy conditions that check the actual class, like `def readonly?; self.class === MyProtectedClass ? true : super; end`, but that can quickly end up in a mess - it's probably cleaner to directly override the readonly? method in every model class you want to modify.

Comment: Btw, instead of overriding the readonly? method in a model, it is probably more unobtrusive and 'cleaner' to simply add an after_find callback that sets every record to readonly: `def after_find; readonly!; end`

Comment: Maybe use this with an environment variable instead of returning true or false directly.

Answer (score 4):

Zargony's solution seems to be the best one, but I would like to add to it a bit.

So, about his code:

This works nicely. A good solution is to add this in an initializer and run this code only if an env var is set, so that you can choose whether to run the app in read-only mode on launching the app.

```rb
if ENV['READ_ONLY'] == 'true'
  module ActiveRecord
    class Base
      def readonly?
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then run the server from command prompt like `READ_ONLY=true bin/rails s`. Also, adding

```rb
rescue_from ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord, with: ->() {
  flash[:alert] = "The site is running in read-only mode. We are going to return to full operation soon. Thank you for your patience!"
  redirect_to root_path
}
```

to the ApplicationController (that all of your controllers should inherit from) is a nice way to show the users what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Permissions plugin? Something simple like cancan where you define what a user can do, when. It will allow you to display links, or not, and restrict access to controller actions. The railscast will explain better than I can.

http://github.com/ryanb/cancan

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Answer (score 2):

Another good one which I liked a little better is [Declarative Authorization](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization)
which is covered by Railscasts as well: [Railscasts - Declarative Authorization](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Zargony will work well but raise an exception if your application is trying to write anything. If you want your application to fail silently on writes so that it doesn't show error pages on each operation (e.g. if you update a timestamp on login in your code, you will get an exception), you can use the approach below:

```
   unless Rails.env.test?
      class ActiveRecord::Base
        before_save do
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "Read-only"
        end

        before_destroy do
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "Read-only"
        end
      end
    end
```